# Servlet 3.1 - Security Constraints - Without web.xml

Tags: java, security, servlets, web.xml

The Java Servlet 3.0 and 3.1 specifications allow developers to perform many of the common configuration based tasks in Java code rather than via the traditional mechanism of providing a web.xml file.

I have all of this working for my application, but upon looking to tackle application security, I could not find any reference to how or if it is possible to also configuration application security constraints via code.

Basically, I am looking for a programmatic way to do the following:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>my-secure-webapp</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>SSORole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>SSORole</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Is anyone aware of a means to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find details in the section provided by Mark, but for short hand, you could put in your servlet something like:

```
@ServletSecurity((httpMethodConstraints = {
    @HttpMethodConstraint(value = "GET", rolesAllowed = "SSORole"),
    @HttpMethodConstraint(value = "POST", rolesAllowed = "SSORole",
    transportGuarantee = TransportGuarantee.CONFIDENTIAL)
})
```

However there are still some drawbacks of using annotation in web module security:

- your `url-pattern` will be direct match to your servlet mappings - cannot define `/*` for whole application like via `web.xml`
- unfortunately still there is no annotation for `login-config`

So I'd suggest to stick with `web.xml` for security definitions for a bit longer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to read section 13.4 of the Servlet 3 specification.